# How to use $ilike in combination with $contains on array of objects in sequelize?

Tags: json, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two columns in postgres with JSONB datatype viz. 'category' and 'subcategory'. I need to make search on these columns on the basis of input from user. JSON in 'category' column looks like:

```
[{id: 36, name: "categoryName1"},{id: 42, name: "categoryName2"}]
```

and JSON in 'subcategory' column looks like:

```
[{id: 52, name: "subCategoryName1"},{id: 56, name: "subCategoryName2"}, {id: 70, name: "subCategoryName1"}]
```

Input can be 'id' or it can be a 'name'.The Query I have written as far tries to find exact same name in both the columns as per provided input. But I want to allow user to find even by partial name so trying to use `$ilike` operator. Query is as follow:

```
Model.findAll({
        where: {
          $or: {
            category: {
              $contains: [{
                "name": {
                  $ilike: '%' + term + '%'
                }
              }]
            },
            subcategory: {
              $contains: [{
                "name": {
                  '$ilike': '%' + term + '%'
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      })
```

RAW QUERY:

```
SELECT "category", "subcategory" FROM "table" AS "table" 
WHERE "table"."category" @> '[{"name":{"$ilike":"%subCategoryName2%"}}]' 
OR "table"."subcategory" @> '[{"name":{"$ilike":"%subCategoryName2%"}}]'
```

Comment: why ilike!? I think you should use $like without cotation

Comment: I want to make search case insensitive. I tried `$ilike` with and without quotation.

Comment: 1) the [operator](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/) is `$iLike` (note the upper-case `L`) 2) you probably cannot mix `$contains` with anything else. PostgreSQL does not have any simple operator to do that. On SQL level, you could use a [(`LATERAL`) JOIN through `jsonb_array_elements()`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+like+json+array), but I doubt that sequelize will do this for you implicitly.

Comment: @AnshulMasne Did you ever find a solution to this? I am trying to achieve the same thing

Comment: @KinaraNyakaru No, I did not get solution for this using sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

this could be your answer:

```
   {
    subcategory: {
        $contains: {
          name: {
              $ilike: '%' + term + '%'
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this one also. Its not working. I tried `$or` and `$contains` taking as array and object as well. none approach worked

Comment: what is your sequelize version? if you use older versions the notations should be change @Leo

Comment: I am using Sequelize 3.23.4. @farhadamjady

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for this using sequelize

```
{
                        'category.name': {
                            $iLike: `%${value}%`
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_path_exists` function, which checks if JSONB value matches a path expression with wildcards. Here is the solution

```
Model.findAll({1 where: { [Op.or]: [ 
    Sequelize.literal(
        jsonb_path_exists(
            category, '$[*] ? (@.name like_regex "${term}" flag "i")')), 
    Sequelize.literal(
        jsonb_path_exists(
        subcategory, '$[*] ? (@.name like_regex "${term}" flag "i")')) 
]}});
```

You can read more about `jsonb_path_exsits` function here: [#postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING)